# Clever 5x5 grid of alphabets in C#

Tags: c#, html, nested-loops

I have to print a 5x5 table with alphabets in them, like:

```
<table>
 <tr> <td>A</td> <td>B</td> <td>C</td> <td>D</td> <td>D</td>
```

etc.. the letters are in fact a link, so they will be like:

```
<td> <a href='/someplace'>A</a> </td>
```

Those links have all the tendency to change often and I don't fancy hard-coding them and replacing them since they will be appearing in quite a few pages. So I thought I would write up a function to output the whole structure.

Yes, it's pretty straight forward, get the `for` loop to behave like:

```
  StringBuilder alphabets = new StringBuilder("<table class='table'>");
  for(int i=65; i<=87; i++)
  {
      //Do stuff here to calculate if i mod 5 is zero and add <tr> accordingly.
      //Use Convert.ToChar(i); to get the wanted structure.
  }
```

Then it hit me, I could possibly do it in a better, "clever" way using nested for loops,

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    alpbahets.Append("<tr>")
    for(j=1; j<5; j++)
    {
        //Get the <a > link string here.
    }
    alphabets.Append("</tr");
}
```

Now the question is, what can I do to relate `i` AND `j` to get them into the range of 65-87?
<sub>(A-W, since it's a 5x5 grid I will skip the last iteration and manually add `YZ` in one `td`)</sub>.

I have tried `(i*10 + j) + 54)` <sub>(yea, I don't know what I was thinking)</sub>, but it doesn't work.

This might be an EXTREMELY stupid question, sorry, but what is the way to get this done in nested `for` loops? Or is there any other better way? I am asking because I am very curious to know more (and dumb that I already don't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about just introducing a variable `char letter = 'A';` out side your loops?

Then after using it, call `letter++;` to move to the next letter in the alphabeth.

This will make your program more readable also, and won't force other programmers to see some calculation including i and j that ends up as a letter.

Simplicity is often the best solution :)

Comment: WOW!! I had no idea I could increment chars! this has to be the most cleverest and simplest idea ever! 10 vote ups for you, thanks so much!

Comment: damn, I forgot my password (and I used a dummy email to avoid spam) so I cant get into my original account (locustHorde) and so I dont have enough rep to vote up :(

Comment: @Alexander - No problem. Glad to hear it helped you out ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  alpbahets.Append("<tr>")
  for(j=0; j<5; j++)
  {
        int val = 65 + i*5 +j;
        //get the <a > link string here
  }
  alphabets.Append("</tr");
}
```

Comment: oh man, I spent about 30 minutes to create that formula, havent tested it because char++ seems too good to me, but thanks so much for answering, you are clever!

Answer (score 1):

Use zero based indices for i and j and then the formula:

```
 int x = (i*5) + j + 65;
 if (x<=87)
     printCharacter(x);
```

Comment: glad to help! fyi, the stackoverflow way to say thanks is to upvote

Comment: I really do want to vote up several posts here, but I dont have enough rep. I will re-visit when i have do make it past 15 reps. thanks again

Comment: ah I see, though I think you can upvote 30 times a day, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq. upvoting wont lower your rep

Answer (score 1):

I say go for the simple char option already suggested,

That said it can also be done in the loop like this, though its not the most readable code I've ever written.

```
StringBuilder alphabets = new StringBuilder("<table class='table'>"); 
for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
  alphabets.Append("<tr>\n");
  for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
  {
        alphabets.Append("<td><a href=\""+"linkGoesHere"+"\">"+ (65+i*5+j<91?Convert.ToChar(65+i*5+j):' ') +"</a></td>\n");
  }
  alphabets.Append("</tr>");
}
alphabets.ToString().Dump();
```

Note the ternary operator to ensure the last few cells are blank rather than special characters.

Comment: Hi Robb, what is the use of using `ToString().Dump()` ? wont just 1ToString()` work? and why will it ever go to special characters?

Comment: @Alexander - When I'm working with a snippet like that I use LINQPad, .Dump() is a method within that to display a variable in the results pane.  As for the special characters, once it reaches `Z` its still got 4 iterations of the inner query to go so you get the special characters that follow on. `[`,`\ `,`]` and `^`

Comment: Oh, linqPad sounds very interesting. regarding the last few extra chars, cant we avoid it by making `i and j` both to `<5` instead of `<5`. this will skip Z but  I can add it manually at the end

Comment: @Alexander - Yep if we make `i<5` then it would work and you can output your last line manually.  Linkpad is available here http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: thank you very much! I dont know linq but I will definitely start learning it

Comment: @Alexander - Linq is quite nice for querying but rarely what I use linqpad for, if you set its mode to c# statements you can run small snippets of code like the above.  It's great for testing little bits of code in isolation without cluttering up your harddrive with lots of console apps

Comment: I downloaded Linqpad. its so amazing! I usually open up new visual studio instance to test code snippets like these but whoa! one heck of a time saver! I am already addicted to it! thanks so much for the tool I might stalk you from now on and upvote your every single answer and comment hehehe

Answer (score 0):

If you could output these as floated divs inside a container, rather than as table cells, you could then use a repeater control on the front end (containing a single floated div) and bind the repeater to an array of your required letters (takes care of Y and Z as well).

Comment: I know, I was so wanting to do this but I am, as my job title says, `interim web developer` and the `information architect` in this company doesnt seem too friendly to suggestions! sigh!